# Create phylogenetic visualisation using ape package in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny web application to take newick input files from the user and then visualise the trees on the screen. I am trying to use the ape package to do this however I am getting stuck writing the server function in my shiny app. Would anyone be able to adjust my server function to be able to achieve the visualisation while also having some logic to detect the type of file that is being uploaded as well?

I have tried the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(ape)

ui <- navbarPage("Visualisation Toolbox", 
                 tabPanel("Phylogenic Trees",
                          fluidRow(
                            class = "inputs",
                            column(6, align = "center",
                                   h4("Select File Type:"),
                                   selectInput(inputId = "file_type", "", 
                                               choices = list("Newick" = "newick", 
                                                              "NEXUS" = "nexus",
                                                              "Phylip" = "phylip",
                                                              "RAxML" = "raxml"),
                                               selected = "newick")
                            ),
                            
                            column(6, align = "center",
                                   h4("Select Tree File:"),
                                   fileInput(inputId = "tree_file", "",
                                             buttonLabel = "Browse")
                            ), 
                            plotOutput('contents'),
                            )
                 ),
                 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myPlot = reactiveVal()
  myData = reactive({
    input$tree_file
    myPlot(ape::read.tree(data))
    data
  })
  
  output$contents = renderPlot({
    myPlot()
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand fully what you mean by having some logic to detect file type. However the following example achieves visualization and plots conditionally on `input$file_type`. It may serve as a starting point.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ape)
ui <- navbarPage("Visualisation Toolbox", 
                 tabPanel("Phylogenic Trees",
                          fluidRow(
                            class = "inputs",
                            column(6, align = "center",
                                   h4("Select File Type:"),
                                   selectInput(inputId = "file_type", "", 
                                               choices = list("Newick" = "newick", 
                                                              "NEXUS" = "nexus",
                                                              "Phylip" = "phylip",
                                                              "RAxML" = "raxml"),
                                               selected = "newick")
                            ),
                            column(6, align = "center",
                                   h4("Select Tree File:"),
                                   fileInput(inputId = "tree_file", "",
                                             buttonLabel = "Browse")
                            ), 
                            plotOutput(outputId  = 'contents'),
                            )
                 ),
                 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$contents <- renderPlot({
        file <- input$tree_file
        if (is.character(file$datapath)) {
            if (input$file_type %in% c("newick")) 
                plot(ape::read.tree(file$datapath))
        }})
}
```

Comment: Thats amazing! It worked thank you so much! 
I was thinking about implementing some kind of switch() statement within the server function to make sure that the user uploaded the correct file type depending on what they selected and if no, an error would pop up from shinyalert! E.g:

`file <- input$upload_tree$datapath
output <- switch(
    input$file_type,
    tree = possibly(read.tree, otherwise = NULL)(file),
    beast = possibly(read.beast, otherwise = NULL)(file),
    etc ...
)`